# Give name to Python make altinstall

Tags: linux, python-3.x

I do install multiple versions of Python, compiled from sources.
For example, when I do `make altinstall` for Python 3.6.3, it was installed as python3.6 and pip3.6 symlinks in /usr/local.

When I next do `make altinstall` for Python 3.6.6, I don't know what symlinks were created. I tried supplying name i.e. `make altinstall python3.6.6` but it didn't work.

How do I do `make altinstall` for Python 3.6.5, when the symlink python3.6 already created for Python 3.6.3 from prior installation?